# Field Won't Show in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The following field won't show up on my signin page, why not?

In `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_AssociateID">
    <DisplayName>Associate ID - associateId</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="associateId" />
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="associateId" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

I've added it to my TechnicalProfile

```
...
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AssociateID" />
...
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AssociateID" Required="true"/>
```

---

To debug it, I've added a bunch of variations and they all work.

[image: fields that do work]

the label is {id after extension} - {PartnetClaimType}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw in the towel and decided to use the associate_id field name even though that was not what I wanted and then associate_id stopped working too.  This lead me to the fix.

The fix was to remove it from my `OutputClaims` in my TechnicalProfile `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName`

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="DoNotUse" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_associate_id" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organization_id" />
    </PersistedClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_associate_id" /> --> 
    </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```